# How to duplicate items and upper case each item?

Tags: msbuild

In MSBuild, it's easy to duplicate a property and upper case the value:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <Name>Sarah</Name>
    <UpperName>$(Name.ToUpper())</UpperName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

How can I duplicate each item of item type Names, upper case it, and create a new item type UpperNames ?

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Names Include="Tim" />
    <Names Include="Sam" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```xml
<UpperNames Include="@(Names->ToUpper())" />
```